# Redirecting FIFO in runtime in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ipc

I am trying to implement a runtime reconfigurable IPC in C++ under Linux using POSIX IPC. In the current configuration I have a process A communicating through a FIFO with a process B. The process B takes the data from the FIFO, make some modifications and sends them to another process C through another FIFO. Here's a graphical representation:
[image: 1]

Then, at run-time I would like to kill the process B, and be able to allow process A to send the data through the FIFO between B and C:

[image: 2]

How can I do that?

Comment: Close the existing FIFO in process A and open the one used by process C in write-only mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you kill a process, its open filedescriptors are all closed. So if you kill B, this will cause an EOF on the FIFO as seen by C. However, if you have a named FIFO that persists after B is closed, C can continue to read from the filedescriptor associated with the FIFO, although it will return EOF immediately continuously until the other end is reopened.

Another option is to have B send its output back to A, which then forwards that output to C. This way, it will always control what gets sent to C, and C does not have to worry about its FIFO being closed and reopened.

Comment: Yes, I already solved in this way the problem of closing the program and losing the descriptors. My question was more about if there was a possibility, without interfering with the processes A and C to make a software link between the two FIFOs (a sort of soft link). I think that the best solution is to notify the process A that the process B is being closed and that the FIFO to use it becomes then the one of C.